# How do I copy/yank a multi-line expression I typed at the ZSH prompt?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

For example, supposed I'm browsing through my history, and reach this multi-line command I'd typed earlier:

```
~ >> for f in *; do
echo $f
done
```

I've enabled `vim` bindings in the ZLE (`bindkey -v`), so I can type <kbd>Esc</kbd> at this point and use `vim` keys to get around, move across lines, etc. I can also do <kbd>yy</kbd> to yank the current line. However, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to copy all these lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

There are two (admittedly cumbersome) approaches that come to mind. The first is to use Vim, the second a small utility for Urxvt (if that is your terminal emulator):

- While in your history, hit <kbd>v</kbd> to open the current command in your `$EDITOR` (which is Vim, naturally) and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> to select all of the lines before <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>*</kbd> to yank it to your clipboard.
- You could also use [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls) for this (and other) enhanced functionality in the terminal, including yanking and pasting. In this case: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> to enter selection mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to select all of the lines and <kbd>y</kbd> to yank them to the buffer, before <kbd>q</kbd> to quit. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> pastes the yanked text.<sup>1</sup>

The first approach seems the most direct, assuming there isn't some straightforward way to do it just using Zsh's line editing capability.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1. These keybinds are all configurable in your `~/.Xresources`</sup> 

<sup>2. Which wouldn't surprise me...</sup>

Comment: Yes, I did think of the $EDITOR approach, but as you said, that is quite cumbersome. I'd prefer not having a terminal emulator based approach, since I split my time between iTerm2 on Mac and gnome-terminal on an Ubuntu box.

Comment: @MilindGanjoo Yes, I'm looking forward to an answer that just use Zle myself...